# display pie chart using highcharts api and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

I have a query. I want to display a pie chart using the highcharts api. The data is coming from a MySQL database. My table is like (THIS IS MY TABLE FORMAT):

```
city|area|blank
A   |100 |50
B   |50  |20
```

My PHP code is

```
<?php

include "con.php";

$id = $_GET['city'];


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT   area AS A , blank  AS B from `table`  WHERE city = '".$id."' ");

$rows['type'] = 'pie';
$rows['name'] = 'area';
//$rows['innerSize'] = '50%';
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows['data'][] = array($r['A'], $r['B']);    
}
$rslt = array();
array_push($rslt,$rows);

print json_encode($rslt, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
mysqli_close($con);
```

I have been displaying a pie chart but my data was like this (THIS IS EXAMPLE):

```
id|category|value
1 |area    |100
1 |blank   |20
2 |area    |50
2 |blank   |20
```

but as I mentioned regarding my table structure earlier, the pie chart is not displaying with it.

My js code:

```js
var c = $('#City :selected').text(); 

                 getAjaxData(c);
     
 var opt = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container1',
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'final chart'
                    },
                    
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                color: '#000000',
                                connectorColor: '#000000',
                                formatter: function() {
                                    return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.y;
                                }
                            },
                            showInLegend: true
                        }
                    },
                    series: []
                };
                function getAjaxData(c) {
                $.getJSON("file.php", {city:c},function(json) {
                    opt.series = json;
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(opt);

                }); 
    
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Where is your JS code?

Comment: it does not need but i have add it

Comment: And what does this `print json_encode($rslt, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);` code print for you?

Comment: what is pie chart look like?

Comment: You should have something like `[10,20,30]` or preferably `[{name: 'A', y: 10}, {name: 'B, y: 20}, {name: 'C', y: 30}]` as data.

Comment: i know this but data is entered in the horizontal form

Comment: Can you please send output of your PHP code

Comment: pie chart is not displaying "container1" is blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer to plot pie chart using highcharts api. when data is in horizontal format.

```js
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT   area AS A , blank  AS B from `table`  WHERE city = '".$id."' ");

$rows['type'] = 'pie';
$rows['name'] = 'values';
$p = 'area';//add this variable for the datalables
$a = 'blank';//add this variable for the datalables
//$rows['innerSize'] = '50%';
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows['data'][] = array($p, $r['A']); 
    $rows['data'][] = array($a, $r['B']);    
}
$rslt = array();
array_push($rslt,$rows);


print json_encode($rslt, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, your data is in the dreaded "entity-attribute-value" format which is...[complicated](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios).

That means that instead of writing a nice query like

```
select area, blank from cities where id=1
```

you now have to wrangle the data from rows into columns in all your queries

```
select c1.value as area,
  c2.value as blank
  from cities c1
  inner join cities c2 on c1.id=c2.id
  where c1.category='area'
  and c2.category='blank'
  and c1.id=1
```

I'd suggest not using EAV to store your data.